# How to move a search navigation link to another position?

Tags: search, navigation

I have added a link programmatically to the global search navigation. See code below. The link is added as last. Is it possible to add to second location ? In the gui it is possible with the buttons "up" and "down".

```
private void AddLinkToSearchNavigation(SPWeb web, string pageUrl, string title)
        {
            // define new link
            SPNavigationNode node = new SPNavigationNode(title, pageUrl, false);

            // check if the link exists
            if (web.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl(node.Url) == null)
            {
                web.Navigation.AddToSearchNav(node);
            }

            web.Update();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SPNavigation** object has a property named **SearchNav**.

This propery is a **SPNavigationNodeCollection**.

A **SPNavigationNodeCollection** object contains a **Add** method with two parameters. Syntax looks like this :

```
public SPNavigationNode Add(
    SPNavigationNode node,
    SPNavigationNode previousNode
)
```

**The node parameter:** The node object (SPNavigationNode) to add to the collection.

**The previousNode parameter:** Specifies the position in the node collection at which to add the new node object by identifying the node previous to the position where the new node is inserted.

So, using this method, you should be able to specify the position of your navigation link.